# Is there a specific way to create a lib/shared? Standalone nx angular app

Tags: angular, architecture, shared-libraries, nrwl-nx, angular-standalone-components

Is there a recommended approach for creating a shared library or folder in an Angular application for reusable components, pipes, and directives that can be used across different parts of the app?

While I know that standalone components can be imported directly into other components, I'm wondering if there's a preferred method/structure/architecture, possibly involving the creation of a library, for organizing and sharing these resources in a more structured way.

I have a standalone nx angular app project.

I know how to create a lib, I know how to create a component but when I create a lib for example it creates the component in it as well so then I have to remove it. It works but it just doesnt feel like its the right approach, I might be wrong

Comment: To double check - standalone as in 1 project structure rather than `"standalone": true` components right?

Comment: @AndrewAllen actually both, so standalone components with a standalone angular application setup with NX

Comment: ok I'm more familiar with monorepo structure but a shared-ui library should seems the common approach. If you're splitting you're app into domains then you might have a domain/shared-ui if this is isolated to that domain. Don't get too bogged down on this - it's cheap in nx to move libs around using generators.

Comment: so if I have my app: src/app/ models,services, components folder

should I create a shared folder / lib inside of app or should it be outside src on the same level?

And one more thing is it wrong to just create a simple folder, or should I generate a lib (which will also generate a component) which I then remove and create my own pipes, components etc with nx? @AndrewAllen

Comment: recommend implementing modular structure from the nx [tutorial](https://nx.dev/getting-started/tutorials/angular-standalone-tutorial#creating-local-libraries). Organise by feature as libs first aka routed areas of your application (these act like ngmodules used to). If you're new to Nx just have features + shared libs only. Put things in folders (models/services/components) within libs after. You can just delete the generated component if it's not applicable which is often the case. Keep it as simple as you want though. Libs help define boundaries with the bonus of simple imports

Comment: Thanks You can just delete the generated component if it's not applicable which is often the case. this made me feel more comfortable, I felt I was doing something wrong first.

Last question - so I should not create all my components in src/app/components folder? should I instead create libs for each page/feature? and is that through a manual create folder way or create-lib with nx? @AndrewAllen

Comment: for a small app components folder is fine but once you get to a certain size it hurts more than helps. Each page/feature?...you can (and I have) but more typical is a group of routes e.g. feat-stock vs feat-product, with a bunch of related routes in each. Sightly fatter feature libs keeps your shared libs smaller. It's a balance. Then within the libs have smart-components (your pages) and dumb ui (you can split this into a lib later) with a lib.routes.ts hooking them all up, via loadChildren. I do a lot of generation via nx console, copying command it generates as a template for more

Comment: The goal is to have things that change together stay together and ideally match the relevant business concern you're in (read up on domain driven design but I don't actually recommend its final conclusion of microservices). You want to be able to work on one feature and be done, move onto the next.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually few ways to do what you're trying to achieve, each with pro and cons.

*Using a custom library:*

If you build a custom library you can then import it in each standalone component you need. Bundle size would be greater than the second approach. Also, keeping the library and the front-end updated it's not always that easy, especially when is not done regurarly.

*Using a shared folder in the same application*

This approach can be useful if you don't need to bring this components, pipes, etc in other projects as well. You also will need to import the desired component, pipe, ... in all your standalone components. You could also create a `sharedModule` that import and export all of your shared things and just import the module in the needed components (Could lead to be a bit overkill if the moudule has large quantity of items).

> I have a standalone nx angular app project.

The cons of using a full standalone project is that if you have, let's say, ten components that use the same `foo.pipe`, you'll need to import it in each of them.

This can be frustrating, but it gives the developer full control on what's going on without having to define a lot of modules for each scenario.

There are few school of thougths on how to structure an Angular project, but there's not a standard.

*So, as a recap:*

Answers on this topic would all be opinion based, which are kinda forbidden here on SO. The approach to use is up to you. I used both (custom library and shared folder) and it just depends on the project. In term of performances there is no difference.

Comment: I'm not going with the option with modules and/or a monorepo. I have a standalone angular application setup with NX. I know that I will have to import each pipe/component/directive into the component if I want to use it from the shared/lib. But I'm wondering where would it be suitable to have that shared folder or lib and should it be created manually a folder or through some command?

Comment: To use a shared folder or lib is way too opinion based, so it's up t you. for the second question, it's still up to you. I personally create all files manually, I can't be bother to open another terminal just to do some `ng g c ...`.

Comment: What about necessary config that has to be added for tests or other stuff that nx generates?

One more question, if you have a standalone angular app with NX
all views / features are you supposed to build it in each libs or can you just create everything in src app with components structured?

Comment: If I remember correctly nx generates all that for you, so you may want to customize those configs and organize them as you please. I, for example, usually make a directory `config` in the root dir where I put all the jest configs, proxies, ecc files. For the second question, each workspace works as a standalone since you're not going with the monorepo approach. There is a package called `module federation` that may help you out with that tho. Basically you could have separated projects / libs that shares _stuff_ in a sort-of monorepo way, without having a monorepo structure.

Comment: In any case, these are just my toughts, I hope someone else will comment on this topic to give his/her own opinion.

Comment: I appreciate the opinions that you have. It's a standalone for now but in the future I'll migrate it into a monorepo app in another app but for now it will be standalone.

Can you explain shortly what module federation is and what's used for? I'll also have a google on it but its always easier with a few sentences from a devperspective. Cuz, as I said I want standalone components, no modules.

Comment: NX did generate some stuff when I tried it out but honestly I'm not so experienced with those configs so I wasn't sure if it was correct.

I wanted a shared/lib with components in it but it created something like:
libs(with configs)/shared(empty)/src/a component
then i re structured and did like:
libs/shared/src/pipes(created manually a folder)/then my pipe created with nx
I know its hard maybe to understand but do you think its OK?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255539/discussion-between-almightysosa-and-jacopo-sciampi).